# Increasing Capacitance of a capacitor at constant voltage and frequency in a resonant circuit

Tags: electromagnetism, electric-circuits

A question in my textbook; If a RLC circuit is in resonance case, show what will happen to the hot wire ammeter's reading at increasing the capacitance of the capacitor at constant potential difference and frequency.

So does it decrease as increasing the capaticance at constant frequency and p.d. ends resonance so the total impedence increases and the current decreases?

Comment: Series or parallel resonance?

Comment: Series RLC circuit

Comment: What happens to the impedance of a capacitor if you increase its capacitance holding the frequency constant?

Comment: The Capacitive reactance decreases, thus the total impedence increases according the the formula Z = root(R^2 + (XL - Xc)^2)